# Is there a common pattern for initializing object on a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, background, parallel-processing

I have an object that takes a long time to be initialized.  Therefore I the capability to Start Initializing on application startup.  Any subsequent calls to methods on the class we need to have a delay mechanism that waits for the class to finish initialization.

I have a couple of potential solutions however I am not entirely satisfied with either of them.  The first uses Task.Delay in a while loop and the second uses SemaphoreSlim but involves some unnecessary blocking.  I feel this must be a fairly common requirement, can anybody provide some advice on how to best manage this?

Oh btw, this is a Metro application so we have limited API's

Here is the pseudocode:

```
public class ExposeSomeInterestingItems
{
    private InitialisationState _initialised;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _waiter = 
        new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public async Task StartInitialize()
    {
        if (_initialised == InitialisationState.Initialised)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Attempted to initialise ActiveTrackDown" +
                "loads when it is already initialized");
        }

        _initialised = 
            InitialisationState.StartedInitialisation;

        new TaskFactory().StartNew(async () =>
        {
            // This takes some time to load
            this._interestingItems = 
                InterestingItemsLoader.LoadItems();
            _waiter.Release();
            _initialised = InitialisationState.Initialised;
        });
    }

    public InterestingItem GetItem(string id)
    {
        DelayUntilLoaded();
        DelayUntilLoadedAlternative();
    }

    private async Task DelayUntilLoaded()
    {
        if (_initialised == InitialisationState.NotInitialised)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error " +
                "occurred attempting to access details on " +
                "ActiveTrackDownloads before calling initialise");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (_initialised == InitialisationState.Initialised)
            {
                return;
            }

            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
    }

    private async Task DelayUntilLoadedAlternative()
    {
        if (_initialised == InitialisationState.NotInitialised)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Error occurred attempting to access details " + 
                "on ActiveTrackDownloads before calling initialise");
        }

        try
        {
            await _waiter.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            _waiter.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about not making the instance available (keep it null) until it is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a better design would be an asynchronous factory, where the *calling* code `await`s the object creation and then receives a regular object instance.

Stealing liberally [from Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx):

```
public class AsyncLazy<T> : Lazy<Task<T>> 
{ 
  public AsyncLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : 
      base(() => Task.Run(valueFactory)) { }

  public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) : 
      base(() => Task.Run(taskFactory)) { } 

  public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return Value.GetAwaiter(); } 
}

public static class ExposeSomeInterestingItemsFactory
{
  public static AsyncLazy<ExposeSomeInterestingItems> Instance
  {
    get { return _instance; }
  }

  private static readonly AsyncLazy<ExposeSomeInterestingItems> _instance =
      new AsyncLazy<ExposeSomeInterestingItems>(() => new ExposeSomeInterestingItems());

  public static void StartInitialization()
  {
    var unused = Instance.Value;
  }
}

public class ExposeSomeInterestingItems
{
  public ExposeSomeInterestingItems()
  {
    // This takes some time to load
    this._interestingItems = InterestingItemsLoader.LoadItems();
  }

  public InterestingItem GetItem(string id)
  {
    // Regular logic. No "delays".
  }
}

...

var exposeSomeInterestingItems = await ExposeSomeInterestingItemsFactory.Instance;
var item = exposeSomeInterestingItems.GetItem("id");
```

That way, you keep the Single Responsibility Principle nicely:

- `AsyncLazy<T>` combines `Task<T>` with `Lazy<T>` (so the instance is created asynchronously only when needed).
- `ExposeSomeInterestingItemsFactory` contains construction logic.
- `ExposeSomeInterestingItems` is only concerned with exposing interesting items, rather than having to pollute all its members with asynchronous delays.

Also, this solution is asynchronous throughout (no blocking), which is good (particularly for Metro apps).

**Update, 2012-09-14:** I've taken this code and cleaned it up and commented it [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).

Comment: i was reading over this code at the exact time you edited it - and I got a notification it had changed so going to check out the blog now :-) thanks

Comment: Wayback Machine version of the expired link is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20111108055240/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Task<T>` for this. This will take care of all the synchronisation for you and allows you to block untill the value is available:

```
private static Task<HeavyObject> heavyObjectInitializer;

// Call this method during application initialization
public static void Bootstrap()
{
    heavyObjectInitializer = new Task<HeavyObject>(() =>
    {
        // creation of heavy object here
        return new HeavyObject();
    });

    // Start running the initialization right now on a 
    // background thread. We don't have to wait on this.
    heavyObjectInitializer.Start();
}

// Call this method whenever you need to use the object.
public static HeavyObject GetHeavyObject()
{
    // Get the initialized object, or block untill this 
    // instance gets available.
    return heavyObjectInitializer.Result;  
}
```

Optionally, you can also query to see if the object is available or not:

```
public static bool IsHeavyObjectAvailable
{
    get { return heavyObjectInitializer.IsCompleted; }
}
```

Comment: Note that any exceptions raised by heavy object construction will be wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the method calls into a queue which you process when you finish initialising.  Only put methods into the queue when you have not yet initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You could move to a an event driven architecture where you application is in different states.

Initially the application moves into the **Starting** state. In this state `HeavyObject` is created using a background task. When the initialization is complete an event is fired. (You don't have to use an actual .NET `event`. You can use callbacks or something similar and frameworks like Reactive Extensions allows you to compose sequences of events.)

When all initialization events have fired you move into the **Started** state of your application. For an UI application this could modify the UI to enable some previously disabled operations.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Prototype Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). Maybe it can help you

You only need to create your object once and clone it when you need another one.